# DOM manipulation - Multiple forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have several forms on my page (via a loop), each have it's own submit button.
I want to use AJAX to get and POST the data to a .php. I need to know which form was submitted so I can get the corresponding values.

It's a simple cart application. This form allows a user to change the quantity of the items in the cart before checkout.
[image]

You see that there are two "Change Quantity" buttons (sumbit buttons) and these two fields are wrapped in a form tag.

The loop that encloses the form is :

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
  $item_code = $row['product_id'];
  $item_name = $row['name'];
  $item_price = $row['price'];
  $item_qty = $row['qty'];
  print"<tr>
  <td>
    <img src='http://localhost/store/images/products/$item_code.jpg'>
  </td>
  <td>$item_code</td>1
  <td>$item_name</td>
  <td>$$item_price</td>
  <td>
    <form method='post' action='/store/processing/view_cart.php' class='cart_view_ajax' id='form_id_$item_code'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' value='$item_qty' id='qty'>
      <input type='hidden' value = '$item_code' name='product_id' id='product_id'>
      <div><input type='submit' id='submit' value='Change Quantity'></div>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>x</td>
  </tr>";
}
```

The Question : 
How do I know via jQuery that which form was submitted? Help me out...

According the given answers, I've managed to get the Quantity of the submitted form like this by jQuery. Here's the code :

```
    $('form.cart_view_ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // start working
    var form = $(this);
    var form_id = form.attr('id');
    console.log($('#'+form_id).children().eq(0).val());

    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$('input[type=submit]').click(function() { var allFormInputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input'); })` or `form.find(':input')`

Comment: @Terminus which is basically the same. I want specific input tags (the first one and the second one). Your code will list all of the inputs. That's why I've included the eq().

Comment: I just like that selector and thought it would help. If you want a specific input(s) why not echo them out with a class or name that you can select by so you won't have to worry if you reorder them at some future date?

Comment: @Terminus exactly what I was thinking.. What if I re-order these inputs? I know this jQuery code isn't very 'dynamic'.. Good Idea!

Comment: This should be the correct id selector: `#form_id_' + form_id`. You don't even need to use children and eq if you give the input a class. Drop the id='qty' because it's not unique

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the 'product_id' because it should be unique to each item

```
<input type='hidden' value = '$item_code' name='product_id' id='product_id'>
```

Or you can add an unique ID property to the form tag

```
<form method='post' action='/store/processing/view_cart.php' class='cart_view_ajax' id='item_$item_code'>
$('form#item_3')
```

You can add an unique id to the row so can manipulate it later on and you can access the form later on.

```
<tr id="row_$item_code">
$('tr#row_3 form')
```

You can add 'data' attributes to the form

```
<form method='post' action='/store/processing/view_cart.php' class='cart_view_ajax' id='item_$item_code' data-form_id="$item_code">
var form_id = $('form#item_3').data('form_id');
```

Can we see the jQuery code you are currently using?

Comment: I like this idea, Similar to the one below it. I can then just use simple dom methods like children and eq() to get the value for each input.. I'll try this out.. Thanks!

Comment: I've included the jQuery code that I'm using based on your answer... Look to see If I'm doing it correctly ?

Comment: it looks pretty ok to me, try to make each input id unique by adding the actual item id, you can't have multiple elements on the same page with the same id

Answer (score 0):

You may use another hidden input field that contains an identifier for that special form. I think that would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: ... and then use $(this) to get the children and then eq(x) the x one, which i will know, would be the 3rd one (depends on where I place the hidden field) and then get it's attr() or maybe val().. Hmm, Nice idea dude.